# Relevance algorithm

Tags: mean, weighted

Let's say I want to order some products based on two variables: rating and the number of ratings.

For example, let's say I have these 2 products:

Product A
4.9 of 10000

Product B
5.0 of 1

It's kind obviously that the product A should come first. Probably using weighted mean, but what weight to use for each variable?

Comment: This should be useful: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: I read it, but the problem is that is not using a 5 star scale. =/

Comment: Just make `2.5` a neutral rating. Anything above that will be positive and anything below will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Product A has a rating of 4.9 and it has 10000 ratings. So,(sum of 10000 votes)/10000 = 4.9
Therefore,the sum of 10000 votes = 4.9*10000.

If you need to find which Product to choose,you do use:

4.9*10000/5 = X
and 
5*1/4.9 = Y

Then perform a comparison of X and Y. Its basically comparing hoe the reviews stack up against one another.